# Asp.net mvc razor read passed value to modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I got a list a buttons, that passes indicators Id and opens bootstrap modal. I found how to pass this value, but didnt found how to get it. Here is my code:

```
@model Project.Models.Survey

@{
    var i = 1;
}

@foreach (var Clasificator in Model.Clasificators)
{
    <h2>@Clasificator.Name</h2>
    <br/>
    foreach (var Criteria in Model.Criterias)
    {
        if (Criteria.ClasificatorId == Clasificator.Id)
        {
            <h3>@Criteria.Name</h3>
            <br/>
            foreach (var Indicator in Model.Indicators)
            {
                if (Indicator.CriteriaId == Criteria.Id)
                {
                    <h4> @i @Indicator.Name </h4>
                    <br/>
                    <button id="@Indicator.Id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-indicatorId="@Indicator.Id">
                        Add New Object
                    </button>    
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               // Catch here indicator Id
               If (indicatorId)
               {}

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is possible to catch it ? I need to use that value in other if.

Comment: What if are you talking about ? Please add that code.

Comment: updated code , check please

Comment: You wont have access to the "selected IndictorId" value from the razor file. The modal is opened with javascript. So you probably need to write some javascript to get the value as the modal opens, then do an ajax call to build the rest of the modal